# Irrationality measure of log(2)/log(6)

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

As part of my Phd thesis on aperiodic Wang tilings, I've discovered I need a bound on the irrationality measure of $\gamma = \log 2/\log 6$.  That is, I am looking for an upper bound on the quantity

$\eta = \inf \{\alpha : \left|\frac{\log 2}{\log 6} - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{q^\alpha} \text{ for only finitely many $p,q\in\mathbf Z$}\}$.

I have found a paper *An explicit lower bound for a homogeneous rational linear form in logarithms of algebraic numbers* by E.M. Matveev.  This paper gives a complicated system of parameters which can be adjusted bound the irrationality measure of rational linear combinations of logs.  From this I have managed to obtain the bound

$\eta < 10^9$.

Does anyone know of references that can produce a better bound on this quanity?  Perhaps one closer to its likely value of 2?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

See Georges Rhin: Approximations de Padé et mesures effectives d'irrationalité. (French) [Padé approximants and effective measures of irrationality] Séminaire de Théorie des Nombres, Paris 1985–86, 155–164, Progr. Math., 71, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 1987.

Inequality (8) there shows that if $u_0$, $u_1$ and $u_2$ are integers with $H= \max(|u_1|,|u_2|)$ sufficiently large, then  we have 
$$ 
|u_0+u_1\log 2 + u_2 \log 3| \ge H^{-7.616}. 
$$ 
Thus $\eta \le 8.616$.

I don't know a free online version for Rhin's paper (you can find it on Springer Link).  But you can look at [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2003-72-242/S0025-5718-02-01442-4/S0025-5718-02-01442-4.pdf) by Qiang Wu in Math. Comp. which discusses similar problems and mentions Rhin's work (which seems the best known result for the $\log 2$ and $\log 3$ case).

Comment: This is great.  I've contacted Rhin about his paper.  Thank you.

Comment: Excuse me Lucia but could you explain the : "Thus η≤8.616" ? Thank you in advance. SXBnano

Comment: @SXBnano If log(2)/log(6) - p/q = +- 1/q^alpha, then q log(2) - p log(6) = +- 1/q^{alpha - 1}. Rewriting the LHS as (q - p) log(2) - p log(3), the theorem above asserts that 1/q^{alpha -1} >= max(p, q-p)^{-7.616}. As log(2)/log(6) is around 0.38 the q-p term is larger, and is at least q/2. So one finds 1/q^{alpha - 1} >= 2^{7.616} q^{-7.616}. Taking logarithms, (1-alpha) log(q) >= 7.6 log(2) - 7.616 log(q). Taking q large establishes alpha <= 8.616.